# If $\deg(p(x))=k$ and $p(T)=0$ then $\dim(Z(T,v)) \leq k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space above $\mathbb F$. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator, $v\in V$ a vector, and $p(x) \in \mathbb F[x]$ a polynomial, such that $\deg(p(x))=k$ and $p(T)=0$.

If $Z(T,v)$ denotes the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$, then prove that $\dim(Z(T,v)) \leq k$.

How can I approach this?

Comment: Note that since $p(T) = 0, T^k(v) \in \operatorname{span}\{T^iv: i < k\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_kx^k,a_k\neq 0$, then $p(T)(0)=a_0+a_1T(0)+...+a_kT^k(0)=0$

So $a_0=0. $ And $p(T)(v)=a_1T(v)+...+a_kT^k(v)=0,a_k\neq 0$ implies that $\{T(v),T^2(v),...,T^k(v)\}$ is a linearly dependent set, hence so is the set $\{v,T(v),...,T^k(v)\}$. So $\dim(Z(T,v))<k$